# Using Ack.vim's quickwindow in vim

Tags: vim, ack

I am using ack.vim with vim. I get my search results back in a vim quickwindow which is great. Only problem is that I have to hit [enter] to open the file that's displaying in the quickwindow. On thee ack.vim [github](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) site it says

> In the quickfix window, you can use:

```
o to open (same as enter) go to preview file (open but maintain focus
on ack.vim results) 
t to open in new tab T to open in new tab silently
q to close the quickfix window
```

But they don't work for me. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the latest version of Ack.vim?

My version was old, so these mappings didn't work for me (they weren't set anywhere in the script, in the latest version they are around line 51).

Now that I've installed the latest version they work as advertised (except for a weird empty window when using `T`).